Is there a way to determine if I've loaded a google maps library, like marker?
If I dynamically load a library like this:
const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await 
google.maps.importLibrary("marker") as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;

is there any way to determine if the library has been loaded? And if I call it again in the same component, will it make the call and load it again? If yes, how do I avoid this redundancy?

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await - and why would you ever need to call it multiple times in a single component? That doesn't make sense.

@MyUpsidown  Well, I don't want to call it multiple times, but let me ask a couple of questions. If I load the "marker" library dynamically will it still be available on other pages(components) or do I have to import it again on that page? (I have like 10 pages using maps and markers). 2nd question, can I load multiple libraries at once? I see this link https://mapsplatform.google.com/resources/blog/more-control-loading-maps-javascript-api/ and it shows multiple imports at once but I'm not sure about the syntax and don't know how to access each library.

You mentioned loading the libraries multiple times in the same component. Now you are talking about different components. I don't know your app structure. Loading it multiple times in the same component would not make sense as I already mentioned. And yes you can load multiple libraries at once. As it stands, your question is unclear/too broad.

@MrUpsidown ok maybe I should edit my post. My issue with dynamic loading is handling a page like Airbnb's listing page (listing on one side and map with markers on the other side). I feel like I'm going to run into a race condition between fetching the listing results from the server and fetching the maps library from Google and not having a page rendered to display the map. The issue is order of operations! I wish I could find an example online of this type of page and how it's handled.
